# Remote Desktop Connection problem with multiple login attempts

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

We have a common machine with Windows XP installed; anybody can remotely connect to it. The problem is when user called A is already connected to that machine remotely and doing something, if some other user B remotely connects to it user A is not warned that somebody else is trying to connect; the session simply gets disconnected and the other user takes control of the system. How do we resolve it ?

Requirements:

- Anybody can remotely connect to that machine
- If a user is already connected he should be warned and he has to say 'OK' or 'Cancel' so that the other user can connect
- If the logged in user allows the new user to connect, then the new user should see the same screens, basically the same session should be continued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Real [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/download.html). Here you can share screen. You can configure it to allow only single remote user at a time or multiple concurrent users.

It works up to XP & Windows 2003 & on LAN. (Need to buy paid version for Vista support). Also since its screen sharing, you get the same screen & the same session.

(NOTE: From Vista onwards, in RDC, the current remote logged-in user gets a prompt when another remote user tries to login.)

Answer (score 1):

Would netmeeting remote desktop (included free with XP) be a solution?

Try typing 'conf' from the run box (without the quotes)

or look at this [Microsoft KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/233175)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable multiple concurrent connections using RDC. This might solve your problem; you can look over [this](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/06/13/enable-multiple-concurrent-remote-desktop-connections-or-sessions-in-windows-xp/) article for more information.

Comment: This is a "hack" that might not be appreciated by the poster's company IT department (if, as I think, this question is in a corporate context) ?!

Comment: It is a hack, but it's better than nothing :)

Comment: Yes, I am restricted from doing this hack :)

Comment: Then I suggest you try a different remote client, if possible. Try looking on SuperUser for different other apps for remote access.